# Model combines more than one model always is sent empty to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have one model that combines more than model always is sent to controller as empty model

**Model**

```
namespace Test.Models
{
    public class Compination
    {
        public firstmodel fmodel{ get; set; }
        public secondmodel smodel{ get; set; }

    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model Test.Models.Compination
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post)){
<div>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstmodel.Name, "Name")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstmodel.Name)
</div>
   //other fields
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id){
     firstmodel FM= db.firstmodel.Find(id);
     ClassA object = methodA(id);
     secondmodel SM = object.secondmodel; 
   var Compination= new Compinati
on{ firstmodel= FM, secondmodel = S};

            return View(Compination);
}
```

**By this way name for example is empty**

```
public ActionResult Edit(Compination comp){
 var name=   comp.firstmodel.Name;
 //other code }
```

**But if i have assigned name for each item in each model it's pass the values correctly like this**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstmodel.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Name = "Name" })
```

**then in controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(string name){
     // Now name isn't empty
     //other code }
```

I do not want to call each item separately I want the whole model

Comment: Why not just use a viewmodel comprised of the things you need from the two other models?

Comment: When you call your controller method you are passing only an Id, or even null.  At that point your controller has no knowledge of the model info that was on the page, you didn't give it any.  This article explains various methods of transferring model info back to the controller https://www.teamscs.com/2015/09/asp-net-mvc-5-passing-data-view-controller/  -- check out view model binding.  it allows you to pass the entire model back to the controller, you need an input for each model element on the form, or those elements will be null.

Comment: @TJ Wolschon sorry I did not understand what your comments

Comment: @programmer do you know what a View Model is? If you do not, try finding out more about them. They are very useful for what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks @TJ Wolschon I searched about this now it's very useful I will try to use it now thanks again

Comment: Never ever ever attempt to change the `name` attribute - the `HtmlHelper` methods always generate the correct `name` attribute - which in your case is `name="firstmodel.Name"` which binds correctly. Because you changed it - nothing will bind correctly